# Javascript recursion, foreach loop won't exit?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I build a simple Javascript treeview, where every Node has a name, a list of children and an ID:

```
class Node {
  constructor(name, childNodes, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.childNodes = childNodes;
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

My Aim is to create a function "getNodeById(parent, id)", that returns the Node with the given ID. I have tried using a recursive method, but there has to be a mistake somewhere:

```
function getNodeById(currentNode, id) {
  if (currentNode.id === id) { console.log("found"); return currentNode; }
  currentNode.children.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child);
    return getNodeById(child, id);
  });
}
```

My idea is, that the function will search through the childNodes and call itsself again. When the the correct node is found, it should be returned after the if-statement, then inside the foreach loop. The function finds the right node successfully but it won't stop and return the Node. Here is the output when calling getNodeById(parent, 2);

[image]

Why doesn't the function exit after the "found"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a short circuit with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return a stored node, if found.

> `some()` executes the `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a *truthy*  value (a value that becomes `true` when converted to a Boolean).

```
function getNodeById(currentNode, id) {
    var node;
    if (currentNode.id === id) {
        return currentNode;
    }
    currentNode.children.some(child => node = getNodeById(child, id));
    return node;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks! I just don't quite understand the some-loop. As far as I can tell, after finding the right node, the loop will go on and will return the empty "var node".. How does it work?

Comment: no, after finding a node, the loop stops, because the return value is truthy.

Comment: Okay, sounds great, but how does the function know, whether an element of the class "Node" is true or false?

Comment: the function returns either `undefined` if no node is found or an object, the node, which is a truthy value.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getNodeById(currentNode, id) {
  if (currentNode.id === id) { console.log("found"); return currentNode; }
  for(node = 0; node < currentNode.children.length; node ++) {
    const foundNode = getNodeById(currentNode.children[node], id);
    if(foundNode) {
      return foundNode
    }
  }
  return undefined
}
```

This should work!!

Answer (score 2):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> A simple loop
>
> A for...of loop
>
> Array.prototype.every()
>
> Array.prototype.some()
>
> Array.prototype.find()
>
> Array.prototype.findIndex()
> The other Array methods: every(), some(), find(), and findIndex() test the array elements with a predicate returning a truthy value to determine if further iteration is required.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I thought return always breaks the function.

Comment: @Basti In `map` what your return becomes a new value in the resulting array and `forEach` is `map` except the returned value is never used. `return` or making it to the end if the function indeed returns to the callee that will call the function with the next element regardless of the previous answer and this happens in every single level on it's way back to the root. `some` and `every` examines the result at each call because ethey short circuit when they know the ultimate result.

Answer (score 1):

`getNodeById()` doesn't return anything. You are returning from the right arrow function which the `forEach()` take and doesn't doing anything with. Use a for loop.